# mongodb array size aggregation size failing

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hello I've looked the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/
 and from what I read, if I have an object with an authors attribute and inside it I have multiple authors a.k.a array I should do it using size inside aggregation but I get an error:

If I hit db.posts.find().pretty()  I get this:

```js
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58c7e35a8a00f209be819771"),
 "allReviewsLink" : "link somewhere",
 "totalReviewCount" : "200"
}
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("58c7e515be41d40a39954a38"),
     "authors" : [
      "Linda",
      "Benn",
      "Carolyn"
     ]
    }
```

And this is what I tried without success:

```js
db.posts.aggregate(    [       {$size: {"$authors"             }          }           ] )
```

Where posts is my collection and I get the following error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:63

Comment: Use `$size` operator with `$project` stage. Something like `db.posts.aggregate(    [ {$project:{ size: {$size: "$authors"  }}} ] )`

Comment: I don't believe you need `$` in front of attributes like `authors`

Comment: I edited my question, maybe it helps to clarify.

Comment: Use `db.posts.aggregate( [ {$project:{ size: {$size: {$ifNull:["$authors", []] }}}} ] )` to accomodate the non - existent fields. Or alternatively you can use `$match` to filter those documents before `$project` stage

Comment: Yes!!! this is the answer mate. Please answer it so I can validate it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it couple of ways.

This query will set the non-existent `authors` values to a size 0.

```
db.posts.aggregate( [ {$project:{ size: {$size: {$ifNull:["$authors", []] }}}} ] )
```

Or alternatively you can filter documents using `$match` first and then calculate size.

```
db.posts.aggregate( [ {$match:{authors:{$exists:true}}},{$project:{ size: {$size:"$authors" }}} ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $Project in aggregation,

```
          db.posts.aggregate( [ {$project:{ size: {$size: {$ifNull:["$authors", []] }}}} ] )
```

Comment: the above command should return size: 3,whats your expected output?

Comment: oh ok , are you using mongoshell to execute this command, or something else? , for me i have executed this command in mongodb 3.2 shell

Comment: yes mongoshell and I get the following: Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing",
 "code" : 17124,
 "codeName" : "Location17124"
} : aggregate failed :

Comment: yes sorry, for null scenario we need to add empty array for $size, i edited my answer